# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: bankapp_userregistermodel.date_of_birth i m getting this error when i create the superuser

Tags: python, django

**please help me how to solve this**\

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
    from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
    
    class MyuserManager(BaseUserManager):
        def create_user(self, mobile_number, password=None):
    
            if not mobile_number:
                raise ValueError("user must have an mobile number")
                
            user = self.model(mobile_number = mobile_number)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)
            return user
    
        def create_superuser(self, mobile_number, password=None):
            user = self.create_user(mobile_number, password=password)
            user.is_admin = True
            user.save(using=self._db)
            return user
    
    class UserRegisterModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        mobile_number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Mobile Number", unique=True)
        bank_ac = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        user_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        email = models.EmailField()
        date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=False)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=160)
        pin_code = models.IntegerField()
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
        objects = MyuserManager()
    
        USERNAME_FIELD = "mobile_number"
    
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.mobile_number
    
        def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
            return True
    
        def has_module_perm(self, app_label):
            return True
    
        @property
        def is_superuser(self):
            return self.is_admin

admin.py

    from django.contrib import admin
    from bankapp.models import UserRegisterModel
    from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
    
    class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
        list_display = ['bank_ac','first_name','last_name','user_name','mobile_number','email','password','date_of_birth','address','pin_code']
        list_filter = ['bank_ac']
        search_fields = ['mobile_number']
        ordering = ['mobile_number']
        filter_horizontal = []
        fieldsets = []
        add_fieldssets = [
            [None, {
                'classes' : ['wide',],
                'fields' : ['mobile_number','email','password'],
            }],
        ]
    admin.site.register(UserRegisterModel, UserAdmin)

forms.py

    from django import forms
    from .models import UserRegisterModel
    import datetime
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    
    
    class LoginForm(forms.Form):
        mobile_number = forms.CharField(label='Mobile Number',
            widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Your Mobile Number',
                'class':'form-control'}
            )
        )
        password = forms.CharField(label='Password',
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={'placeholder':"Enter Your Password",
                'class':'form-control'}
            )
        )
    
    class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
        repassword = forms.CharField(label='Re Enter Password',
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Re Enter Password', 'class':'form-control'})
    
            # forms.DateField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
        )
    
        class Meta:
            model = UserRegisterModel
            fields = ['bank_ac','first_name','last_name','user_name','mobile_number','email','date_of_birth','address','pin_code','password','date_joined']
    
    
            widgets = {
                'bank_ac': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name', 'class':'form-control'}),
                'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name', 'class':'form-control'}),
                'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name', 'class':'form-control'}),
                'user_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'User Name', 'class':'form-control'}),
                'mobile_number': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name', 'class':'form-control'}),
                'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'class':'form-control'}),
                'date_of_birth': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
                'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Addeess', 'class':'form-control'}),
                'pin_code': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Pincode', 'class':'form-control'}),
                'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password','class':'form-control'}),
            }
    
    
        def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super().clean()
            pwd = self.cleaned_data["password"]
            rpwd = self.cleaned_data["repassword"]
            if pwd != rpwd:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Both Passwords must be same')

views.py

    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from bankapp.forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm
    from bankapp.models import UserRegisterModel
    from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
    from django.contrib import messages
    
    def Home(request):
        return render(request, 'home.html')
    
    def RegistrationView(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RegisterForm(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'Registration Successful')
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Unsuccessful Registration. Invalid Informtion')
        form = RegisterForm()
        return render(request, template_name='bankapp/Registration.html', context={'register_form':form})
        
    def LoginView(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('mobile_number')
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    messages.info(request, f'You are now logged in as {username}.')
                    return redirect('/')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'invalid username or password.')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'invalid username or password.')
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request=request, template_name='accounts/login.html', context={'login_form':form})
    
    def logoutView(request):
        logout(request)
        messages.info(request, "You have succesfully Logged out.")
        return redirect("/")
        # HttpResponse ("Logout Successfully")
```

> File
> "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 85, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py",
> line 416, in execute
> return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
> bankapp_userregistermodel.date_of_birth
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\sms14\Projects\MyProjects\omkarbank\manage.py", line 22, in
>
> main()   File "C:\Users\sms14\Projects\MyProjects\omkarbank\manage.py", line 18, in
> main
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py",
> line 425, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py",
> line 419, in execute
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 373, in run_from_argv
> self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
> return super().execute(*args, **options)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 417, in execute
> output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 195, in handle
> self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
> File "C:\Users\sms14\Projects\MyProjects\omkarbank\bankapp\models.py",
> line 21, in create_superuser
> user = self.create_user(mobile_number, password=password)   File "C:\Users\sms14\Projects\MyProjects\omkarbank\bankapp\models.py", line
> 17, in create_user
> user.save(using=self._db)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py",
> line 66, in save
> super().save(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
> line 743, in save
> self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
> line 780, in save_base
> updated = self._save_table(   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
> line 885, in _save_table
> results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)   File
> "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
> line 923, in _do_insert
> return manager._insert(   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py",
> line 85, in manager_method
> return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
> line 1301, in _insert
> return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)   File
> "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
> line 1441, in execute_sql
> cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 99, in execute
> return super().execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 67, in execute
> return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   File
> "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
> return executor(sql, params, many, context)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 80, in _execute
> with self.db.wrap_database_errors:   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
> line 90, in **exit**
> raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 85, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\sms14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py",
> line 416, in execute
> return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
> bankapp_userregistermodel.date_of_birth

Comment: Your model is abstract from the user model. and the date_of_birth field is null=false. Make null=true or give date_of_birth while creating a superuser

Comment: give date_of_birth "default=datetime.now()" for test

Comment: Is everything perfect MyuserManager class code?

Comment: no I didn't mention it but your MyuserManager.create_superuser does not save password and username

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**thank you for your answer i have changed some code by your answer
it is working thank you very much brother**

models.py

```
date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
pin_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

forms.py

```
def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```